# Chat application writing empty lines

Tags: c#, client, server, chat

I made a chat application (Client + server) with following model:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm

The difference is, that i made the client in a console application too. Here's the code of my Client Class:

```
class Program
{
    static TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
    static NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
    static string readData = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        connect();
        while (true)
        {
        string send = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    private static void connect()
    {
            readData = "Connected to Chat Server...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("localhost", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("somerandomusername" + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
    }

    private static void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
            string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            if (returndata != null)
            {
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void msg()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">> " + readData);
    }
}
```

and here's the code from my Server class:

```
class Program
{
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
        counter = 0;
        while ((true))
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;

            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

            clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

            broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined", dataFromClient, false);

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room");
            handleClient client = new handleClient();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry client in clientsList)
        {
            TcpClient broadcastSocket;
            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)client.Value;
            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;
            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + ": " + msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
            broadcastStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}

public class handleClient
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;

    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                clientsList.Remove(clNo);
                Console.WriteLine(clNo + " hat den Chat verlassen");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow the client displays a lot of empty lines when receiving messages. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoF5B.png. 
above the first red marker there are empty lines. it marks the area where i typed in my message, pressed enter and the server response was written. to see it i would have to scroll down to the red marker. then there are the empty lines. the second red marker marks the area where the next message would appear.

I would be really thankful if you could help me removing this problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer ow not sure if you got the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your problem is here is the fixed code (in the client):

```
private static void getMessage()
{
    while (true)
    {
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        int buffSize = 0;
        buffSize = clientSocket.Available;
        byte[] inStream = new byte[buffSize];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
        string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        if (returndata != null)
        {
            readData = "" + returndata;
            msg();
        }
    }
}
```

You where reading the buffer size into an array you want the available bytes.

David

Comment: you screenshotted the server. i screenshotted the client.

Here's another pic: no i scrolled down. http://i.imgur.com/DSL3m7B.png

Comment: Thanks, but i already got a solution. I just had to trim the recieved byte array, so that there aren't 10025 empty values.

Comment: Up to you but you are reading more bytes than what you need to then.

Answer (score 1):

You are sure you are receiving any text? Are you sending text correctly? Are you getting any errors? Set breakpoints before the broadcast of data and also a breakpoint at the receiving end and check if your variables do contain what you  expect they contain.

Is it not that you are trying to read from the Stream which does not have any data and gives you dummydata what results in the application printing new lines with no text because it just has no text to send?

Are the amount of lines of empty text the same as the length of the string you send?

Comment: I receive the text. I'm not getting any errors and i already set breakpoints. The problem has to be in the part of the server, where the messages are sent. When i use msg() to display a message from the client there are no lines. only when i receive a message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the misuse of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`:
A byte value of 0 will get converted into space, not into `'\0'` as you might suspect. And since you initialize it with 10025 zeros you have a bunch of spaces filling up your lines.
Trimming your `returndata` before appending it to `readData` will solve this problem but will have side effects like not allowing leading and trailing spaces in your message.

You can try this to understand the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] lolempty = new byte[1024];
    string encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(lolempty);
    Console.WriteLine(encoded.Length.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", encoded);
}
```